# Why part of the Apache IoTDB server reported `TTransportException` error when accessing them through python coding?

Tags: python, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When we remotely access the Apache IoTDB database server through python coding, there is no problem on some servers, but this error is reported on the other servers:`Could not set time zone because:RuntimeError:TTransportException('Transport not open' ))`. Does anyone know what may be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the version of Apache IoTDB server is consistent with the version of Apache IoTDB package in the python environment. These two versions should be the same to successfully visit the server.